# How can I make a character that looks like jelly slime

Tags: modeling, sculpting

This is the character name Bobby from the Hotel Transylvania. I want to model this character but I can't figure it out. Can anyone show me how to model the body of this character? no need of eyes only body shape [image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 7):

Create a cylinder, subdivide horizontally with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, select one edge out of 2:

[image]

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to scale, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the selected edges:

[image]

Select the top face, enable *Proportional Editing* and scale down:

[image]

Bevel the slots, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Deform the object with the *Grab* brush in *Sculpt* mode:

[image]

For the head, just extrude up and scale down:

[image]

Comment: This is good. but the head part is not like the image

Comment: For the head, just extrude up and scale down

Comment: @MRchan Maybe you could put a little own effort into the modeling ;)

Comment: @moonboots: 2 cents for your thoughts after reading "but the head part is not like the image" :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: tststs....it is expected here that the answer is pixel perfect to the image which is shown. And of course one sentences as explanation in the question is much more than needed!!! :D

Comment: @moonboots: and yeah, your answer with just 6 images and some text is pretty disappointing, so yeah, +1 for this disappointing answer which is missing not only color and is missing the head part...!!!!! :D :D :D but i think you can improve that....

Comment: :(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: @Chris also the character has 8 belly bulges whereas mine has only 7  ://

Comment: And no sunglasses…the character is nothing without sunglasses. Think of man in black: they would be nothing without sunglasses!!